# GUI box value not updating

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello everyone I have a bar where I display a variable that changes by user input, it is on the OnGUI() of this script:

```
public class StateManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Vector2 pos1 = new Vector2(10,200);
    public Vector2 size = new Vector2(60,20);
    private HydroElectric ec;
    public Texture2D emptyProd;
    public Texture2D fullProd;

    public StateManager()
    {
        ec = new HydroElectric();
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        float tt;
        tt = (ec.HydroControlPanel () / 6 );

        GUI.BeginGroup (new Rect (pos1.x, pos1.y, size.x, size.y));
        GUI.Box (new Rect (0, 0, size.x, size.y), emptyProd,GUIStyle.none);
        GUI.BeginGroup (new Rect (0, 0, size.x *tt , size.y));
        GUI.Box (new Rect (0, 0, size.x, size.y), fullProd, GUIStyle.none);
        GUI.EndGroup ();
        GUI.EndGroup ();

    }
}
```

This variable can go from 0 o 6 so I divide it to get a 0 to 1 scale to reveal the bar. The value I am calling with the dot sintax comes from here:

```
public float HydroControlPanel ()
        {
            turbina1 = t1Bool ? 2 : 0;
            turbina2 = t2Bool ? 3 : 0;
            turbina3 = t3Bool ? 1 : 0;

            prod = turbina1 + turbina2 + turbina3;
            return prod;
        }
```

The Bools are changed using toggle buttons which are working because in other script I have this value showed like this:

```
Public void ShowIt()
        {
            ec.t1Bool = GUI.Toggle (new Rect (25, 55, 100, 50), ec.t1Bool, "Turbina 2 MW");

            ec.t2Bool = GUI.Toggle (new Rect (25, 95, 100, 50), ec.t2Bool, "Turbina 3 MW");

            ec.t3Bool = GUI.Toggle (new Rect (25, 135, 100, 50), ec.t3Bool, "Turbina 1 MW");

            GUI.Box (new Rect (Screen.width - 100, 60, 80, 25), ec.HydroControlPanel().ToString ());      // PRODUCED ENERGY

        }
```

How I can make my bar update? It starts showing the default value but never changes after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line

```
tt = (ec.HydroControlPanel () / 6 );
```

You're dividing float by integer, so result will always be integer. You should divide by float:

```
tt = (ec.HydroControlPanel () / 6f );
```